# What's the best way/practice to get the extension of a uploaded file in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form that allow users to upload files, I however need to get the file extension, which I am able to get, but not sure if I'm using the most effective solution

I can get it using the following ways

```
$fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES['File']['name']);
echo $fileInfo['extension'];

$ext = end(explode('.',$_FILES['File']['name']));
echo $ext;
```

Which method is the best to use or are there even better solutions that would get the extension?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`pathinfo($_FILES['File']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

- Use a built-in function whenever possible (what @Sarfraz said in the meantime), *and*
- Extract only the needed information (`options = PATHINFO_EXTENSION`)

Comment: but don't trust the input!  don't allowing any execution of the uploaded files and preferably move the uploaded files outside the `DocumentRoot` so that even if it is executable, the user can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Better way - [fileinfo extension with PHP >=5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php)

**PS:** do not trust file name extension, any user can any how rename the file extension

Comment: Good solution, but for me this won't work because my development environment currently runs PHP 5.1.6

Comment: @Roland - ditch 5.1.* , even 5.2.* is no longer supported ... is time to look for 5.3 , but sometime just too troublesome to upgrade

Comment: I agree with you, but I unfortunately am not the owner of the machine, otherwise I would have upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

The **first** (using `pathinfo`) one is better for the obvious reasons. Use a **built-in** function for a functionality rather than re-creating it :)