# end(explode) Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php, explode

I have this code to get the extension of a file:

```
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["rfile"]["name"]));
```

That is working fine on localhost, but when I upload online hosting, it is giving me this error:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in...

Comment: Did you read on php.net what `end` does and what arguments it acepts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Comment: @Mjh I haven't gone to technical parts, I just got the example from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5427229/2912339

Comment: That's why you should always read if a question has been marked as duplicate. As you can notice, that question is duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591523/whats-the-best-way-practice-to-get-the-extension-of-a-uploaded-file-in-php) which provides the accurate answer. Question you linked is not accurate and shouldn't be used. Sadly, it attracted many visits :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4636166/1255289)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) (`PHP >= 4.0.3`), i.e.:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["rfile"]["name"])['extension'];
```

---

**Live PHP demo**

http://ideone.com/eMpbnL

Answer (score 7):

PHP `end` takes an reference to a variable as argument. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

So, with strict standards enabled, you should put the result of `explode` into a variable first:

```
$exp = explode(".", $_FILES["rfile"]["name"])
$extension = end($exp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your localhost is on an old PHP version or is not configured to display strict standards errors.

Now in PHP, you should do:

```
$explode = explode(".", $_FILES["rfile"]["name"]);
$extension = end($explode);
```

See the example in the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php#refsect1-function.end-examples