# Php codeigniter is not uploading an image

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my view code of uploading an image but it is showing error You did not select a file to upload.

```
<form id="signupForm" action="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/saveSpeciality" method="post">   
  <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text" required=""   name="speciality_Name" placeholder="Speciality Name" >
      <?php echo form_error('speciality_Name','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
  </div>  
        <input type="file"  name="image"  size="20"/>
        <?php echo form_error('image','<span class="help-block">','</span>'); ?>
  <div class="form-row">
         <input type="submit" name="addSubmit"  value="Add Speciality"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is code of my controller dashboard and function is saveSpeciality. when i try to upload image it shows error "You did not select a file to upload.".

```
public function saveSpeciality()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048000';
    $config['max_width'] = '2048';
    $config['max_height'] = '2048';
    $config['overwrite'] = true;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $imag="image";
    if( ! $this->upload->do_upload($imag)){
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
        echo $this->upload->file_name;
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    }
}
```

Comment: ```enctype= multipart/form-data```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You did not select a file to upload. PHP Code Igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115515/you-did-not-select-a-file-to-upload-php-code-igniter)

Comment: only the mistake in form attribute add enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [storing images to folder in php without seperate upload button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307405/storing-images-to-folder-in-php-without-seperate-upload-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>`

Comment: It must be comment not an answer

Answer (score 0):

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your form

```
<form id="signupForm" action="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/saveSpeciality" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`<form id="signupForm" action="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/saveSpeciality" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

```
$file_name = time() . "." . pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|GIF|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
$config['max_size'] = '2048000';
$config['max_width'] = '2048';
$config['max_height'] = '2048';
$config['file_name'] = $file_name;
$config['overwrite'] = true;

$obj->upload->initialize($config);
$imag = "image";
if (!$obj->upload->do_upload($imag)) {
  $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
  print_r($error);
  //return $obj->upload->display_errors();
} else {
  $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
}
```

Comment: i have test this code previous error is removed but it showing this errro "The upload path does not appear to be valid."

Comment: @RanaUmair do you have uploads folder inside your project?

Comment: in application folder and in project folder i have test it using FCPATH and APPPATH as well in both case same error

Comment: @RanaUmair which `OS` you using if unix then you need to change permission or check folder name is correct or not should be same.

Comment: i am using windows 10

Comment: try this  `uploads\` instead of `uploads/` or do like this `echo $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';'die;`  and send me output

Comment: solved by adding this line             $this->upload->initialize($config);